# Perl LWP: running a script returns an error

Tags: https, perl

I have installed `Bundle::LWP` and after several minuets I'm getting this

```
$ perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)"
6.68
```

which sounds OK. However, running this [script](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596001780/-/raw/master/perllwp_examples/ch01/what_server_type.pl?inline=false)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


# Example code from Chapter 1 of /Perl and LWP/ by Sean M. Burke

# http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/perllwp/

# sburke@cpan.org


require 5;

use strict;

use warnings;


use LWP;


my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $response = $browser->get("http://www.oreilly.com/");

die "Couldn't access it: ", $response->status_line

 unless $response->is_success;

print $response->header("Server"), "\n";

__END__
```

gives this **Error**:

```
$ perl a3.pl
Couldn't access it: 501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) at a3.pl line 25.
```

**How can I fix it** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) Perl's module with:

```
cpan LWP::Protocol::https
```

or use package manager, on Debian and derivative:

```
apt install liblwp-protocol-https-perl
```

It's because O'Reilly default now serve the page in `https` with a redirection, see `curl -v` bellow:

```
$ curl -v "http://www.oreilly.com/"
*   Trying 104.85.21.198:80...
* Connected to www.oreilly.com (104.85.21.198) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.oreilly.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: AkamaiGHost
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://www.oreilly.com/
```

Comment: How can I print more lines than the word `Apache` in that code here: `print $response->header("Server"), "\n";` ?

Comment: Turn next pages and if you are stuck, post a new question =)

Comment: Could you write down here for me the page number where can I find this ? I believe that checking a hint is easier than finding it by myself, i.e. that P<>NP :-)

Comment: I don't have the book. If you learn Perl, do it properly. You should definitely ask a new question if you want a response that is off topic in this comments. I will make a response (or anyone else)

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1781182/perl-lwp-how-can-i-print-the-fteched-result) it is a new question.